# Is Template Toolkit safe against arbitrary code execution?

Tags: perl

If a template is provided to Perl's Template Toolkit, can you ensure that the code generation inside Template Toolkit is sufficiently subsetted to be safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Template Toolkit suffers from multiple different ways to arbitrarily execute code, like this one used in CVE-2019-1978

```
[% template.new({ 'BLOCK' => 'use Data::Dumper; print STDERR Dumper(\%ENV); die' }) %]
```

Do not trust user-provided templates. This [bug is filed upstream here](https://github.com/abw/Template2/issues/245).